# Bending a line segment

Tags: geometry

**REVISED QUESTION**

With the help of the existing answers I have been able to put together [this clearer animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/99czjipvhu), and I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863698/is-this-a-cardioid-or-is-there-a-more-specific-name-for-this-parametric-curve) to discover the shape is called a [cochleoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochleoid).  What I am really trying to find out at this point is the following:

It seems like this curve *should* be perfectly smooth through the point at $(0, 1)$, but because the curve is based on $sin(x)/x$ it is technically undefined at this point, and if I were programming a function to evaluate this curve I would have to add a special case for values near this singularity.  I'm curious if there is any way to re-phrase this equation to remove the singularity and make evaluation of it near zero more numerically stable.

--- Original text of question preserved below ----------------------------------------------------

*Imagine I have a unit line segment going from $(0, 0)$ to $(0, 1)$.  Over time, I want to bend this segment such that it always forms a circular arc (the initial configuration can be considered an arc on a circle with infinite radius).  What shape will the end point trace out, and how can I get the coordinates of that point if I am given as input the angle that should be spanned by the arc length?*

*Edit: Thanks to John Bales below, [this animation](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4hb5hdppdg) accurately depicts what I am trying to describe, although I'm not sure how to render the bent segment itself, which would always connect back to the origin.  Is this shape a cartioid?  Is there a way to rephrase the equation so it doesn't become undefined when the input is zero?*

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. How are you *bending* the segment? Does the segment maintain its unit length? What exactly is the circle that this segment is the arc of? Oh and what is the *end point* you are talking about?

Comment: So are you assuming the point 0,0 always has tangent 0?

Comment: I think they mean that for each radius from 1/2 through infinity, there is one circle (say, whose center lies in the left half-plane on $y=1/2$) passing through the two points. Maybe the end point they're referring to is actually the mid point?

Comment: Suppose the radius of the imaginary circles go from infinite (line is straight) to 1/2pi  (line is bent to a circle with circumference 1.  What is the formula for the end point of the arch.  Can you figure what is codomain/image  of this formula?

Comment: @Jason-- You need to edit your question to specify that the segment is always mapped homeomorphically onto a circular arc of unit length along a circle tangent to the $y$-axis and with center on the positive $x$-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle in radians subtended by an arc of length $s$ on the circumference of a circle of radius $r$ is given by

\begin{equation}
\theta=\dfrac{s}{r}
\end{equation}

In this instance $s=1$ and $r\ge\tfrac{1}{\pi}$. The circle has center $(r,0)$ and radius $r$. The arc $s$ of length $1$ extends upward along the circumference with one end fixed at $(0,0)$ and the other end ends at the point

\begin{equation}
(x,y)=\left(r-r\cos\left(\frac{1}{r}\right),r\sin\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)\right)
\end{equation}

These are parametric equations of the curve.

Here is a desmos.com animation of the curve along which the point moves.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/row6dlgqom

This curve has the following polar equation:

\begin{equation}
r=\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta}
\end{equation}

Here is a desmos.com graph of the polar curve with the particle moving along it. You want just the portion of the curve in the first quadrant.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rbusr85zsc

I think it is interesting that this turns out to be a $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ curve but in the polar coordinate system.

If instead of the interval from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ we bend the unit interval on the horizontal axis along circles with centers $\left(0,\frac{1}{2\theta}\right)$ and radii $\frac{1}{2\theta}$ as $0\le\theta\le\frac{\pi}{2}$ then the ends of the unit arcs along the circles from the origin will trace out the portion of the polar curve

\begin{equation}
r=\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\theta}
\end{equation}

in quadrant I.

The following is a link to a GeoGebra animation illustrating this variation of the problem.

https://www.geogebra.org/m/THDbt3Ad

[image: Still image of GeoGebra animation]

Comment: @Jason   I found the polar equation of the curve and posted a link to an additional graph.

Comment: @fleablood I found the polar equation and graph of Jason's 'bending a line segment' problem and it turns out to be a $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ graph but in the polar plane.

Comment: For some strange reason GeoGebra is speaking Portuguese in the app sidebar today. sen means sin

Comment: how to calculate the arc angle in above equation.