# Is this a cardioid, or is there a more specific name for this parametric curve?

Tags: geometry

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cwtregdvva

The graph above demonstrates the path the endpoint of a unit length stick takes as it bends around tighter and tighter angles (modify the slider for 'a' to see the stick bend).  The red dashed line is a cardioid of roughly the same size.  Obviously these are different shapes.  Is the shape of the blue curve anything special, and does it have a name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [cochleoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochleoid).

$$r = \frac{a\;\sin\theta}{\theta} \qquad\qquad
(x,y) = \frac{a\;\sin\theta}{\theta}(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) = \frac{a}{\phi}\left(\;\sin \phi, 1-\cos \phi\;\right) \quad(\phi := 2\theta)$$

(Of course, your version swaps $x$- and $y$-coordinates.)

Here's a picture of $a=1$:

[image]